# Convert C# function to VB.Net, Lambda problems and best way to convert

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert a block of code from VS2010 C# 4.0 framework to VS2008 VB.NET 3.5 Framework. I am extremely unsure of how to proceed as I am unfamiliar with VB.NET and VS2008 and I am finding the differences between the two environments frustrating. I've gutted most of the irrelvant code from the original C# in hopes of providing a clean example of the problem that a solution can be indicated from.

I did try a few code converters but the lambdas tripped them up.

I converted the first lambda to a simple `For Each` construct which seems fine.
However the second lambda (passed to to the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` call) is causing me uncertainty. As the lambda is using the `taskcount` var which is declared outside the lambda body, I am hesitant on the best approach to to make this code friendly to my target environment (VS2008/VB.Net/3.5) and keep the code as similar as possible to the original implementation. I don't wish to explicitly push the `taskcount` into the `WaitCallback` unless there is no other way.

```
public void sendAndBlock(List<ISendable> msgs)
{
    int taskCount = msgs.Count;
    AutoResetEvent fini = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    msgs.ForEach(m =>
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(nil =>
        {
            this.send(m);
            //threadsafe decrement and if we have no tasks left then unblock.
            if (0 == Interlocked.Decrement(ref taskCount))
            {
                fini.Set();//signal our main thread to proceed
            }
        }, m);
    });
    //block our main thread
    fini.WaitOne();
}
```

Comment: Did you try this (http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)? It might give you a place to start even if the conversion is not totally successful.

Comment: VB.NET lambda's are imo very verbose. I'd remove the first one (ForEach) completly and just do a normal for each.

Comment: That was the first site I tried. THe site worked well for most of the code I was tasked to convert but none of the converters seem to be able to handle Lambdas. SO, your advice is very good but I end up at the point where I am now.

Comment: Do you actually need Visual Studio 2008, or can you use Visual Studio 2010 targeting the .Net 3.5 framework? It makes a difference in what version of VB.Net you're allowed to use. If you can compile from VS2010 for .Net 3.5, you can use the newer vb language syntax features and this gets much easier.

Comment: As a side note, why in the world are you doing this?

Comment: Yes 2008 is a strict requirement indicated on the ticket I am assigned for this task. As to why I am doing this (see previous answer, *sadface*)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the version of VB used with Visual Studio 2008 will require you to break this into three methods (the original, plus one for each of the lambda expressions), because the older version of VB.Net did not yet support multi-line lambda expressions. We have to adapt things so we can fit the lambda expressions into a single line to close over the captured variables properly. If you were to use the same version of Visual Studio, VB.Net would be able to do it in the same way as C# (at least in this case), because the version of VB.Net included with Visual Studio 2010 does support multi-line lambda expressions.

I think this will do it, but check it: I typed all this right into the reply window and it's complicated enough I likely have a mistake or two.

```vb
Public Sub sendAndBlock(ByVal msgs As List(Of ISendable))

   Dim taskCount As Integer = msgs.Count
   Dim fini As New AutoResetEvent(False)

   'vb.net for vs2008 is limited to single-line lambdas.
   ' But we still need to create a closure to capture the fini and taskCount variables
   ' Means we can't translate old code line-for-line
   ' Solution is to abstract the old lambda expressions out to their own methds that we can call in a single line
   msgs.ForEach(Function(m) QueueMessage(m, fini, taskCount))

   fini.WaitOne()

End Sub

Private Sub QueueMessage(ByVal msg As ISendable, ByVal signaler As AutoRestEvent, ByRef taskCount As Integer)
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Function(n) SendQueuedMessage(msg, taskCount, signaler), msg);
End Sub

Private Sub SendQueuedMessage(ByVal msg As ISendable, ByRef TaskCount As Integer, ByVal signaler As AutoResetEvent)
    Me.send(msg)
    'Not sure about this line, because `Set` is a reserved word in VB
    If Interlocked.Decrement(taskCount) = 0 Then signaler.Set()
End Sub
```

I might be able to get this down to two methods instead of three, because one of the extra methods condensed down to a single line, but for the sake of simplicity and readability I'll leave it here.

Finally, if it's enough to just be able to target .Net 3.5 from Visual Studio 2010, you can get by with something closer to the original, because you can use the newer VB language syntax features from Visual Studio 2010 with .Net 3.5.

Comment: THis looks good, I am checking now. You state the problem I am having perfectly (closing over variables).

Comment: Only problem I have encountered, so far, with this solution is that Lambdas cannot take a ByRef parameter. I know I'll take a heat round for this but I moved the taskcount var to a private field and I'm just accessing it by way of scope in order to workaround the lambda ByRef restriction.

Comment: Finished the port of the code using Joels suggested solution. All looks well and has passed my unit tests. Thank you Joel for your help (bows deeply).

Answer (score -1):

```vb
Public Sub sendAndBlock(msgs As List(Of ISendable))
    Dim taskCount As Integer = msgs.Count
    Dim fini As New AutoResetEvent(False)
    msgs.ForEach(Function(m) 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Function(nil) 
                                     Me.send(m)
                                     'threadsafe decrement and if we have no tasks left then unblock.
                                     If 0 = Interlocked.Decrement(taskCount) Then
                             'signal our main thread to proceed
                                     fini.[Set]()
                                     End If

                                 End Function, m)

                End Function)
    'block our main thread
    fini.WaitOne()
End Sub
```

Thanks, [DeveloperFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/)

Comment: He's back-porting for Visual Studio 2008, but I don't think you can use multi-line lambda's in vb.net until Visual Studio 2010. If he just needs .net 3.5, though, and can still compile this on vs2010 or vs2012, then this might work.

Comment: Also, even if you're using VS post-2008, this should have been converted to a 'Sub' lambda, not a 'Function' lambda.

Comment: DeveloperFusion does it wrong here. Even in VS > 2008 this code won’t work because the signatures are wrong (`ForEach` doesn’t accept a `Function`).